# Visual Studio c# error occurs everytime when I revert changes in GitHub Desktop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

Everytime I revert a commit in my project using GitHub desktop I get the following error when I'm trying to debug:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Unknown Module.
> Duplicate type named "Costura.AssemblyLoader" in assembly "Project, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"".

(I translated it because my Visual Studio is in german)

The only thing that helps is repairing or updating Visual Studio through the Installer. When I delete the revert the error still shows up. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and the project is a .net 4.7.2 c# application.

Answer (score 0):

"System.badimageFormatexception" type of unprocessed abnormalities occur in xxxx.exe

Other information: Failure to load files or assembly "xxxxxxx, versions = xxxxxxx, xxxxxxx" or one of its dependencies. Trying to load program with an incorrect format.

The reason is that the target platform of the "target program is inconsistent with the target compilation platform of the dependencies. It is modified to compile all the projects to the same target platform (X86, X64, or AnyCPU), which can generally solve the problem".

Right -click item => Properties => Build => Platform target

[image]

If the above method cannot be solved, the following ways can be used:

Right -click solution => process => Configuration Properties => Configuration Manager

[image]